# Haskell List Comprehension, where x can't be equal to an element of a list

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I want to generate a list of tuples from a list of tuples, where the left part of the tuple only occurs on the left side in all the elements of the list.

Basically what I want is a more generalized version of the following:

```
[ (x,y) | (x,y) <- [(1,5),(5,2)], x /= 5, x /=2 ]
```

If [(1,5),(5,2)] would be a variable called list, then x can't be equal to any of the values of (map snd list). How do I put this condition the list comprehension? (or should I use something else? like filter?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> then x can't be equal to any of the values of (map snd list)

The direct translation of that is

```
x `notElem` map snd list
```

So you'd use something like

```
let xs = [(1,5),(5,2)] in [(x,y) | (x,y) <- xs, x `notElem` map snd xs]
```

If the list is long, that is not efficient, so then you could - if the type permits it, i.e. is an instance of `Ord` - build a set and check for membership in the set

```
let xs = [(1,5),(5,2)]
    st = Data.Set.fromList (map snd xs)
in [(x,y) | (x,y) <- xs, not (Data.Set.member x st)]
```

to reduce the `O(n²)` complexity of the first to an `O(n*log n)` complexity.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful :) I chose to go with your second suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

Construct a [Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html) of all the second elements (let's call it `seconds`), and then just filter by `flip notMember seconds . fst`. You could easily write this as a list comprehension if you really wanted to (but you'd just end up rewriting filter, so why do it?).